# C# based MQTT other than MQTTnet?

Tags: mqtt

I was looking for a C# based MQTT broker which has full open library or api so that we can call those functions in our code to get messages and other relevant data such as list of connections, topics etc.

I am a noobie in this field and programming, I have tried using MQTTnet but i can't get around using it. I have encountered many complications in using it and couldnt get any data from it. I was unable to find any relevant information or help other than its github wiki page. Thats why i was looking for an alternative. If there is any good tutorial on Mqttnet, do let me know. Or if there is any other alternatives.

I have tried Java based MQTTs but getting data from java in c# is not a good idea i think.

Comment: You will do better explaining what you have tried with your existing library and how it didn't work (probably on Stack Overflow) where somebody will either help you fix it, or explain why what you are doing is wrong. Just changing library when it's possibly your understanding of the basics of MQTT may be the problem. (e.g. a client should know nothing about any other clients)

Comment: Also your last sentence doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to have a look at https://sourceforge.net/software/product/MQTTnet/alternatives